traceroute needs the -I option to work
I'm having a problem with the traceroute command: if I want to use it, I have to do so with the -I option whether the Netfilter firewall is enabled or not.
I've tested two different packages with the same result: traceroute and inetutils-traceroute . I currently use inetutils-traceroute.
~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.213.78), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.1.1  3,917ms  1,808ms  1,553ms 
  2   *  *  * 
  3   *  *  * 
  4   * ^C

~$ traceroute -I google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.213.78), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.1.1  3,152ms  2,860ms  3,008ms 
  2   80.10.233.133  30,846ms  28,241ms  31,115ms 
  3   *  193.253.84.233  28,505ms  28,999ms 
  4   193.253.84.146  29,968ms  31,781ms  28,769ms 
  5   193.252.101.101  40,587ms  43,203ms  40,188ms 
  6   193.252.101.173  41,829ms  40,684ms  40,707ms 
  7   *  *  * 
  8   193.251.255.70  44,749ms  49,508ms  44,409ms 
  9   192.178.105.87  44,573ms  43,950ms  44,819ms 
 10   192.178.105.80  60,241ms  49,365ms  45,542ms 
 11   142.251.254.75  47,684ms  92,372ms  49,879ms 
 12   216.239.35.201  51,481ms  *  * 
 13   108.170.230.204  50,290ms  52,156ms  50,562ms 
 14   108.170.255.169  54,177ms  51,390ms  52,840ms 
 15   142.250.224.199  50,606ms  51,508ms  51,388ms 
 16   216.58.213.78  50,002ms  53,672ms  52,492ms 

I think that the UDP packets used as probes don't work on my system (Debian 11), but I can't figure out why. Worse still, I have no idea where to start investigating this problem.

you're right : the firewall on my router was set to the highest level of protection . Many thanks .
